# WPF TreeViewItem Toggle Button visibility

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I've ran into an issue I'm hoping someone can help me solve. I've run into a case where my nodes contain a set of child nodes with visibility set to false. I'm hoping that I can disable the toggle arrow beside the TreeViewItem if all it's children are invisibile. Is this possible? Here's an example:

```
<TreeView Margin="10,10,0,13" Name="TreeView1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="194" Height="200">
    <TreeViewItem Header="Cold Drinks">
        <TreeViewItem Header="Coke" Visibility="False"></TreeViewItem>
        <TreeViewItem Header="Pepsi" Visibility="False"></TreeViewItem>
    </TreeViewItem>
</TreeView>
```

How would i get the Cold Drinks TreeViewItem to hide the toggle arrow?

Comment: I do not know of a simple way.  The only method I know is to change the ControlTemplate for the TreeViewItem.  Here's a link to the Control Template:   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752048.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you see the deafult controlTemplate of TreeViewItem, you will see that visibility of Toggle button is bound to ItemsControl.HasItems. Trigger look like this -

```
<Trigger Property="ItemsControl.HasItems">
  <Setter TargetName="Expander" Property="UIElement.Visibility" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Hidden}" />
     <Trigger.Value>
        <s:Boolean>False</s:Boolean>
     </Trigger.Value>
</Trigger>
```

So, as a workaround, you can create your own Custom Control derived from TabItem and bind your HasItems with your own CLR property which will loop through all your childItems(TreeViewItems) and will return True if any of the Item is visible or False if all items are hidden/collapsed state. That way your toggle button will automatically will hide as per Trigger.

In case you want to know how to create Custom control and bind it to your CLR property, you can refer to this -

[WPF TreeView databinding to hide/show expand/collapse icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2668687/wpf-treeview-databinding-to-hide-show-expand-collapse-icon)

This is somewhat same what you has been looking for. Hope this helps..

Comment: You might also want to look at this - http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/TreeViewWithViewModel.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Both internally (i.e. for keyboard navigation) and in its default template the **TreeViewItem** is relying on its **HasItems** property to know if it has children or not. You will likely need to set the ItemsSource of the TreeViewItem to a list and filter out the collapsed items.